# estimate the launch point and expect the place falling of a shell in the air

Tags: kinematics

suppose that we have a shell in the air, and detected by a particular radar, how do I estimate the launch point and expect a place falling and time will takes to reach its target? 
I want help please! , I don't know where to start..
((I don't care how the missile was detected by radar))
Thanks!

Comment: There would probably be a stochastic estimation algorithm like a Kalman Filter be involved. Now, I am pretty sure that very soon someone will show up and walk you trough some basic Newtonian mechanics and parameter fitting, but that is not how professionals are doing it in the real world.

Comment: "BALLISTIC MISSILE TRAJECTORY ESTIMATION", thesis at the NAVAL POSTGRADUATE SCHOOL MONTEREY, CALIFORNIA by Joseph Dituri, December 2006. There you go... page 11 mentions a Kalman Filter, sadly without much detail. You will get much more detail about a similar problem in e.g. "Multiple moving target detection and trajectory estimation using a single SAR sensor" by Jose M.B. Dias and Paulo A.C. Marques. Look for "trajectory parameter estimation" papers in general.

Comment: I'll add that you switch systems in this. A "shell"  typically does not have an active guidance system. A missile, typically does have an active guidance system and can change course. Nuclear missiles often have multiple warheads.